# Resetting an iPhone with 'No Service' error

Tags: iphone, network, error

A couple of days ago my iPhone 7 started to show 'No Service' error in the upper left corner of the screen. Tried several ways to fix this but nothing helps. While trying to reset it I got the error message:

---

*title:* **iPhone Requires Service**

*body:* You will not be able to set up this iPhone after erasing. A cellular update is required before it can be activated again.

---

What does this mean? Is it safe to proceed?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Did you try getting in touch with your cellular service provider?

Comment: Soft reset is safe, hard reset is not.

Answer (score -1):

Don't reset. 
If you do, then you won't be able to activate your new iPhone. 
Some iPhone7 devices has this "No Service" problem. This is because it can't read your SIM. If you erase this iPhone, it will try to activate but since it can't read SIM you will loose your device.

Comment: why the downvote? He ask if its safe to proceed and I asnwer that This is not safe to proceed. I had this problem before and resseting blocked my phone.